# Bootstrap 4 - Git

Tags: git, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 project. My folder structure is 
    `root/node_modules/` and `root/src/` and `root/gulpfile.js`

I have an `/root/src/scss/` folder as well.

What is the best way to deploy to BitBucket (which files should be deployed) or rather which should be in `.gitignore`? Ideally i'd like to be able to do further dev on this project on another host so would like to be able to replicate the dev env, not just to store the production files.

Comment: Any source code file should probably be versioned by Git, along wtih configuration files shared by everyone.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would this mean i should commit all the node modules as well? and what would be best practice for deployment on production (as I wouldn't need node modules there)? Thanks

Comment: This is a good gitignore: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Comment: @Klooven so you'd suggest I don't store node_modules?

Comment: Yep. There's many reasons for excluding this folder in version control. You can find them by searching a bit on the internet...